# How can I validate a JWSObject that has a "crit" value in its headers?

Tags: java, cryptography, jwt, jose, json-web-signature

I'm trying to write some code to sign and validate payloads using my private/public keys in java following JOSE standards. I need to use the PS256 encryption algorithm for this.

I'm using connect2id's library [Nimbus JOSE + JWT](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt). I'm able to get to the point where I can sign a payload with a private key I load from the file system, and I can also validate it. However as part of my requirements, my header needs to have a "crit" value (explained as part of [RFC-7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.11)).

My problem is the following: As soon as I have a "crit" value in the header, my token validation fails (even if the values in the "crit" array are present in my jws header, as required by the standard). If I take out the "crit", then the signature is validated correctly.

```java
// create RSA key used for signing. 
RSAKey rsaJWK = new RSAKey.Builder(pub)
  .privateKey(priv)
  .keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE)
  .algorithm(JWSAlgorithm.PS256)
  .keyID("KeyID")
  .build();

// Create RSA-signer with the private key
JWSSigner signer = new RSASSASigner(rsaJWK);

// setting critical values to be used in jws header
Set crit = new HashSet();
crit.add("myHeader");

// setting additional parameters for the jws header
Map myParams = new HashMap();
myParams.put("myHeader", false);

// build the jws header with all the values needed
JWSHeader jwsHeader = new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.PS256)
  .type(JOSEObjectType.JOSE)
  .contentType("application/json")
  .keyID("KeyID")
  .criticalParams(crit)
  .customParams(myParams)
  .build();


// build the jws object with the header we created above and a static payload for now
JWSObject jwsObject = new JWSObject(jwsHeader, new Payload("{\"message\":\"In RSA we trust!!!\"}"));

// sign the payload
jwsObject.sign(signer);

// print out the token
String s = jwsObject.serialize();
System.out.println("Your token:" + s);



// To parse the JWS and verify it, e.g. on client-side
JWSObject jwsValObj = JWSObject.parse(s);

JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(pub);

// verify the signature of the parsed token
boolean sigval = jwsValObj.verify(verifier);
System.out.println("Signature Validation passed: " + String.valueOf(sigval));
```

I'm expecting the signature to be verified properly since the values in "crit" are present in the token given.
As soon as I remove the line with `.criticalParams(crit)`, then verification goes through without a problem.

Can someone help me out with this? Am I misunderstanding something or missing some glaring detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [RFC 7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#page-14), **critical headers must be understood by application**, so you need to indicate library that they are deferred to the application for processing

Looking at [RSASSAVerifier](https://github.com/felx/nimbus-jose-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nimbusds/jose/crypto/RSASSAVerifier.java) source code, Try to change

```
JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(pub);
```

with

```
JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(pub, crit);
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, and I missed this when reading through the docs. I hadn't seen any mention of it being required for the verifier, and couldn't figure out why it was being rejected.